# Using svn to control file version for flyway

Tags: svn, flyway, maven-scm

I put all my SQL files in a pool folder in SVN branches and these file have had version already (by SVN revision). The problem is flyway extracts the version info based on the prefix and  I don't want to pay effort to manage this prefix.

Is it possible to remove the prefix name of these file and keep flyway understand the version through SVN revision?

Many thanks!